# c# http request maximum concurrent connections are 40

Tags: c#, http, web, asynchronous, async-await

I would like to create 1000 concurrent http client connections to different URLs.
I have used async/await and waitall.

below is my code

```
static async Task<String> AsyncSend(String url)
{
   HttpClient httpClient = new HttpClient();

   var request = await httpClient.GetAsync(url);
   var responseStr = await request.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
   return responseStr;
}

List<Task> x = new List<Task>();
foreach (var url in URLs)
{
   x.Add(AsyncSend(url));
}
await Task.WhenAll(x);
```

I have 1000 URLS in 'URLs' list.

I see from fiddler that at first it sends 40 requests and waits for them. Then onwards new requests are sent whenever old request response is received.

I have tried 'ServicePointManager.DefaultConnectionLimit = 20000;' and also with app.config with below

```
<system.net>
<connectionManagement>
    <add address="*" maxconnection="100" />
</connectionManagement>
</system.net>
```

And it doesn't increase more than 40 concurrent requests.

Any clue on how to achieve at least 300 concurrent requests .?

Comment: Do you get an exception? Beware of not instanciating a new HttpClient for each request!  
From the docs: `HttpClient is intended to be instantiated once and re-used throughout the life of an application.`

Comment: No exceptions. All 1000 requests are queued. At first 40 requests are sent concurrently, then onwards new requests are sent when previous request's response is received. At any point of time there 40 connections open. Currently 1000 requests takes up to 30 secs. But I want to achieve in 10 secs